# xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11

```
root@mazgalici:~# startx


X.Org X Server 1.7.6
Release Date: 2010-03-17
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-28-server i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux mazgalici 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5.028stab079.2PAE #1 SMP Fri Dec 17 19:34:22 MSK 2010 i686
Kernel command line: quiet
Build Date: 10 November 2010  11:25:26AM
xorg-server 2:1.7.6-2ubuntu7.4 (For technical support please see )
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check 
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jan 11 01:28:48 2011
(==) Using config directory: "/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

Comment: Well, what does `ls -l /dev/tty0` tell you?

Comment: crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 0 2011-01-08 21:32 /dev/tty0

Comment: Reopen. This question should not have been closed. It is related to xorg, a widely used (if not most-used desktop server) desktop server. I have this same error message. Perhaps the question title needs to be changed to "How can I deal with ..." or "What does ... error mean?"

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a modem connected to this machine?  Not sure why it would have group dialout.  That's odd.  What is the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log?  Try running:

```
 startx -- :1
```

Also, what terminal is your user running on?  Run a 'who' to see if anyone else is using /dev/tty0.  Or better yet an lsof on it.